# Is the mode of the sum the same as the sum of the modes

Tags: statistics

If we have $N$ sets, $\{A_{1},\dots, A_{N}\}$, and we form a set $S$ by taking the sum of each element in the set with each element in the other sets, what can we say about the mode of $S$?

Intuitively, I would like to think that we can simply take the sum of the modes, i.e:

$$\operatorname{Mode}(S)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\operatorname{Mode}(A_{n})$$

However, this seems unlikely, especially as we would expect that $\operatorname{Mode}(A_{n})$ could potentially be a set of values, rather than a single value.

So I was wondering if we'd be able to relax this condition to state that $\operatorname{Mode}(S) \subseteq \sum_{n=1}^{N}\operatorname{Mode}(A_{n})$, where we define $\operatorname{Mode}(A)+\operatorname{Mode}(B)$ as the set formed by taking the sum of each element in $\operatorname{Mode}(A)$ with each element in $\operatorname{Mode}(B)$, formally:

$$\operatorname{Mode}(S)\subseteq \sum_{n=1}^{N}\operatorname{Mode}(A_{n})=\left\{\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_{n}: x_{i} \in A_{i}\right\}$$

This seems to be true, but I was wondering if we could say anything stronger?

---

EDIT: I don't think I defined my definition of $S$ clearly enough, for the example $A_{1} = \{2,2,3\}$ and $A_{2} = \{1,1\}$, I would have $S = \{3,3,3,3,4,4\}$, so $S$ should, in general, have cardinality: $$\#S = \prod_{n=1}^{N}\#A_{n}$$ Where $\#A$ is the cardinality of the set $A$.

Comment: I think it might be a good idea to put your excellent clarification into your question. I am removing my answer so others will not get onto the wrong track, and ponder whether I can give a better answer later.

Comment: @BruceTrumbo Thank you, apologies for the lack of clarity in the first instance! I appreciate you taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the multisets $A=\{\!\{0,2,2,3\}\!\}$ and $B=\{\!\{0,2,2,3,5\}\!\}$, both with mode $2$. Then

$$A+B=\{\!\{0,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,7,7,8\}\!\}\;,$$

whose mode is $5$.